# request from form to raw database on django

Tags: python, django, forms

I new with python and django, currently I little a bit confused about how to do my project.

Scenario is simple:
User by using form on fronted is requested weekly statistic of customers and should get list of statistic per customer on selected period (year, week)

So far I able to query data from raw database, function for count statistic start_date and end_date of selected week working fine.

in my models.py

```
def WeekRange(year, week):
    d = date(year, 1, 1)
    delta_days = d.isoweekday() - 1
    delta_weeks = week
    if year == d.isocalendar()[0]:
        delta_weeks -= 1
    delta = timedelta(days=-delta_days, weeks=delta_weeks)
    weekbeg = datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time(00, 00, 01)) + delta
    delta2 = timedelta(days=6-delta_days, weeks=delta_weeks)
    weekend = datetime.datetime.combine(d, datetime.time(23, 59, 59)) + delta2
    cursor = connections['nocdb'].cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT (p.name) AS platform, count(e.id ) AS count FROM event e, lu_platform p WHERE e.platform_id = p.id AND e.sourcetype_id = 1 AND e.event_datetime BETWEEN %s AND %s AND e.sender_id  NOT IN ( 759, 73 ) GROUP BY p.name ORDER BY p.name", [weekbeg, weekend] )
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return results
```

view.py

```
def WeekRequestForm(request):
    form = WeekSelection()
    year = request.POST.get("q_year", "")
    week = request.POST.get("q_week", "")
    currstat_b = [year, week]
    weekstat = WeekRange(*currstat_b)
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'weekstat': weekstat, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
YEARCHOICE = tuple((str(n), str(n)) for n in range(2011, datetime.now().year + 1))
WEEKCHOICE = range(1, 53)

class WeekSelection(forms.Form):
    q_year = forms.ChoiceField(label='Year', choices=YEARCHOICE, initial=(datetime.today().isocalendar()[0]))
    q_week = forms.ChoiceField(label='Week', choices=zip(WEEKCHOICE, WEEKCHOICE), initial=(datetime.today().isocalendar()[1]))
```

With followings I get "an integer is required"
after replace currstat_b = [2013, 48] everything working fine and show me statistick of week 48.

Problem is how to get selected numbers from form to argument in weekstat = WeekRange(*currstat_b)

Also I not sure if is better put raw data function in views or in models as is now.

I will be appreciated for any tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe passing data through form could help, try this:

```
def WeekRequestForm(request):
    form = WeekSelection()
    weekstat = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WeekSelection(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            year = int(form.cleaned_data["q_year"])
            week = int(form.cleaned_data["q_week"])
            currstat_b = [year, week]
            weekstat = WeekRange(*currstat_b)
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'weekstat': weekstat, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Still no luck:Exception Value:  local variable 'weekstat' referenced before assignment

Request information:
GET No GET data
POST No POST data

Comment: Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  an integer is required

POST
Variable  Value
q_year  u'2013'
q_week  u'3'

Comment: could be because of **u'** in year week value?

Comment: @user2859660 maybe, try convert year and week to int: year = int(form.cleaned_data["q_year"]) week = int(form.cleaned_data["q_week"])

Comment: Great, is working with conversion to int. Thank you for your help